# PHP MySQL maths update value in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, addition, subtraction

So ive got a rating system in place on a website im making. Currently each itema has a plus and minus button on either side as well as a visible rating level in this case its 3.1 for one of the items.

Im trying to programme both the plus and minus buttons in such a way that when the user presses them then the rating either increases or decreases by one.

Currently ive only implemented the minus button, however, when I click it the rating value doesnt decrease. It stays at 3.1. The page works fine and when i click on the "minus" button i get the error Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line 67 which is the `$stmt->execute()`

Here is the code i have so far:

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM programmes ORDER BY ProgrammeName ASC");
if ($results) { 
     $i=0;
     echo '<table><tr>';

     echo '<br/>';
     echo '<br/>';

     while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {   
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<div class="tvProgs">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" id = "programmes" action="">';
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"progID\" value=\"".htmlentities($obj->ProgrammeID)."\" />";
        echo '<div class="progImage"><img src="images/'.$obj->Image.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="progTitle"><h3>'.$obj->ProgrammeName.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="progRating"><h5>'.$obj->Rating.'</h5></div>';
        echo '<div id = "btnMin"><input type="button" id ="minus" value ="-"/></div>';
        echo '<div id = "btnPl"><input type="button" id ="plus" value ="+"/></div> ';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</td>';
        $i++; 
        if ($i == 5) {
          echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
     echo '</tr></table>';
}

    if(isset($_POST['minus'])){
        $newRating = 1;
        $ID = $_POST['progID'];

        $upsql = "UPDATE programmes SET Rating = Rating - $newRating WHERE progID='$ID'";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($upsql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

?>
```

Ive kept the ID field hidden as i dont want that to be displayed on the web page. I just want to update the rating of a particular ID.

any informatino will be appreciated

Comment: You've not actually asked a question here. Does the code you have not work? If not, then how does it not work? Or is the issue something else?

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. the code above ive only implemented the Minus button but when the user clicks on it the rating is supposed to decrease by one but it doesnt seem to decrease. It just stays at 3.1

Comment: Would you mind editing your question, and explaining exactly how it doesn't seem to work? Does it generate the page OK, but the links don't work? Is there an issue when you try to do an update? Do you just get a white screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query from:

```
$upsql = "UPDATE programmes SET Rating = Rating - $newRating WHERE progID='$ID'";
```

To this:

```
$upsql = "UPDATE programmes SET Rating = Rating - $newRating WHERE ProgrammeID='$ID'";
```

Hope it should work..

Comment: Mind explaining this fixes the problem? Right now your answer is a little sparse and unclear.

Comment: while storing data into the hidden field he is using $obj->ProgrammeID , so it seems like the field of database is ProgrammeID  but while updating into the database instead of using ProgrammeID , he is updating progID which is hidden field not the database field name.

Answer (score 0):

For using `_POST['some_name']` field on your form should have attribute `name` with value `some_name`

```
<input type="button" name="some_name" value="Some value"/>
```

Currently you have `id="minus"` which is not passed to a server. At least you should have:

```
<input type="button" id ="minus" name="minus" value="-" />
                                 ^ we got name here
```

And second thought - as your `plus/minus` buttons have no `type="submit"` I suppose your form doesn't submit, unless you have some hidden javascript.

Try setting you `plus/minus` buttons like:

```
<input type="submit" name="minus" value ="-"/>
<input type="submit" name="plus" value ="+"/>
```

Comment: I get the error Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line 67 which is the         $stmt->execute(); part of the code

Comment: Search for this error here. Your question has been asked thousand times.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use HTML5 number type input for your `rating`. Depending on the broswer you will have a little spinner that will do this task. Note that not all the broswers render this the same.

```
echo '<div class="progRating">
    <h5><input type="number" id="rating" name="rating" value="'.$obj->Rating.'"/></h5></div>';
```

Then you have to update only the rating with its new value.
More info here: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php

Comment: I did consider that but id prefer if its a normal rating system where the person either presses plus or minus. I would prefer a star system but have yet to be successful at that.